# How to create portable applications?

Tags: application-development, crossplatform

In Ubuntu can you create a portable application and have it work on an OS like SUSE 10.x via USB stick? I'm not sure if this can be done or not, how to do it or if it would be compatible; any advice is greatly welcomed.

I need to make a portable version of Stellarium and have it work in SUSE 10.x. I haven't been able to make portable Linux versions. I'm pretty sure there can be portable versions of applications since you can run a program like TOR on it.

Comment: have you tried to compile it on suse10?
is the architecture of your suse install 32 bit or 64? (I dont recall if suse10 had a 64 bit arch. if you compile the software on your usb, it should be executable from there.  Having a different architecture, or some other fine nuances, might prevent that. try compiling it on your usb stick first, then post errors you might get from compilation, or from trying to run it on your suse10 box.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [Portable Linux Apps site](http://portablelinuxapps.org/), which has a decent collection of portable applications that you can carry in a USB drive and use it on any Linux based OS without worrying about installing dependencies.

Regarding your specific question, you can probably open a thread in their [forum](http://portablelinuxapps.org/forum) and request them to create a portable version of Stellarium.

Or you can take a look at the [documentation](http://portablelinuxapps.org/docs/1.0/AppImageKit.pdf) provided at the site regarding creating portable apps but honestly, it didn't make much sense to me.